# Responsive Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to develop a menu which is responsive. The menu should look like this when not responsive:
[image]

And like the below when screen is reduced for tablets/mobiles:

[image]

You can find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yxMhj/

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>

<div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>

  <ul>
     <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Products</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);

#cssmenu {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {position: relative; z-index: 597; }
#cssmenu ul li { float: left; min-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle;}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default;}
#cssmenu ul ul {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598;}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {top: 0; left: auto; right: -99.5%; }
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul {bottom: 0; left: 0;}
#cssmenu ul ul {margin-top: 0; }
#cssmenu ul ul li {font-weight: normal;}
#cssmenu a { display: block; line-height: 1em; text-decoration: none; }

#cssmenu {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

  #cssmenu > ul { *display: inline-block; }

  #cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
}

#cssmenu a {
    background: #333;
    color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 0 20px; 
}
#cssmenu ul { text-transform: uppercase; }

    #cssmenu ul ul {
      border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 190px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul a {
        background: #1b9bff;
        color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #0082e7;
        border-top: 0 none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 16px 20px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul ul { border-top: 0 none; }

      #cssmenu ul ul li { position: relative }

#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 80px;  }

#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a { border-top: 1px solid #0082e7; }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a { background: #35a6ff; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff; 
}
        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a { border-radius: 0 0 0 3px; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 15px;
          margin-top: -8px;
}

 #cssmenu ul li:hover > a, #cssmenu ul li.active > a {
      background: #1b9bff;
      color: #FFF;
}
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      margin-left: 5px; 
}
    #cssmenu ul li.last ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0; 
}
      #cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 99.5%;
}
.logo{
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20%;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

I really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Have you made any code which can be uploaded

Comment: this is the fiddle I have done : http://jsfiddle.net/yxMhj/

Comment: you must go through
http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/

Comment: No, @ArunMaddheshia, he most certainly does not have to use that plugin. That is potentially an option, but it is definitely not something that he MUST use.

Comment: I do not want the menu to be collapsed in that menu icon, I want the menu to be by default all visible

Comment: try this add below meta tag in head of your html if not added..

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

also add the below css

`@Media screen and (max-width:480px) {
 #cssmenu ul li {
   display: block ;
   width: 100% ;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<style>
    .menu {
        border: 0;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu ul {
        display: table;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu li {
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    .menu li:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .menu a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu li, .menu a {
        text-align: center;
    }

    @Media screen and (max-width:480px) {
        div.menu li {
            display: block !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
</style>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Your logo here</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```